# F# Incomplete pattern matches on this expression when using "when"..Why?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, guard-clause

I have this simple F# function:

```
let compareNum x =
    let y = 10
    match x with
    | _ when x = y -> 0
    | _ when x > y -> 1
    | _ when x < y -> -1
```

However, F# compiler gives me "Incomplete pattern matches on this expression" warning. In this case, all cases should cover every pattern.

I also see a similar example in "Pattern Matching" section in the 1st edition of Programming F# book by Chris Smith. So something might be changed in the later version of F#?

Comment: The compiler assumes that any code with `when` guards is an incomplete match.  It is inelegant, and produces false positives like you saw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incomplete pattern matching a tuple in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354156/incomplete-pattern-matching-a-tuple-in-f)

Comment: Thanks! I like how one of the answer in the above question said, "In general, it is an anti-pattern to have a when guard in the last pattern." I think that makes sense now.

Comment: This is one of those cases where using "if" is not only more idiomatic--it's also a far better way to code the test.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the answer to [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354156/incomplete-pattern-matching-a-tuple-in-f) (and [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691622/f-incomplete-pattern-matches-on-this-expression-when-using-when-why#comment27535581_18691622) -- *"In general, it is an anti-pattern to have a when guard in the last pattern"* -- *by [kimsk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58905/kimsk)*) explain the situation.

However, I would not say that having a guard in the last pattern is an *anti-pattern* - it is the easiest workaround, but I find this somewhat unfortunate, because the `when` pattern gives you useful information about the values you can expect - and that makes understanding the program easier. Last time I had this problem, I left it there, at least as a comment:

```
let compareNum x =
  let y = 10
  match x with
  | _ when x = y -> 0
  | _ when x > y -> 1
  | _ (*when x < y*) -> -1
```

Comment: +1, if you had the equality check `-> 0` as the final pattern it might go some way towards preserving readability without the comment - but personally I think I like this better.