# Is a wildcard always required for union cases of Active Patterns?

Tags: f#

Is a wildcard always required for union cases of Active Patterns?

**Warning:**

> Incomplete pattern matches on this expression.

```
let (|Positive|Neutral|Negative|) = function
    | x when x > 0 -> Positive
    | x when x = 0 -> Neutral
    | x when x < 0 -> Negative
```

The warning is resolved when I insert a wild card as a union case:

```
let (|Positive|Neutral|Negative|) = function
    | x when x > 0 -> Positive
    | x when x = 0 -> Neutral
    | x when x < 0 -> Negative
    | _            -> failwith "unknown"
```

What other cases am I missing?

Comment: You should read the F# specification section  7.2.3 Active Patterns

Comment: Thanks. I reviewed it. However, I did not see the information regarding the warning that I was receiving.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# Incomplete pattern matches on this expression when using "when"..Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691622/f-incomplete-pattern-matches-on-this-expression-when-using-when-why)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`when` guards can't be checked (in general) by the compiler. In this particular case though, just leave out the last guard as you are not missing a case:

```
let (|Positive|Neutral|Negative|) = function
    | x when x > 0 -> Positive
    | x when x < 0 -> Negative
    | _ -> Neutral
```

Note: for `int`, this is OK, `float`s need a few cases more (`NaN` and infinity) and the compiler won't help you there (as you just discovered).