# F# Merge Sort - IndexOutOfRangeException when attempting to implement a match with structure

Tags: arrays, recursion, f#, mergesort, outofrangeexception

The overall code for my merge sort, looked something like this:

```
   let remove array = 
    Array.sub array 1 (array.Length - 1)

let rec merge (chunkA : int[]) (chunkB : int[]) =
    if chunkA.Length = 0 && chunkB.Length = 0 then [||]
    else if chunkA.Length = 0 || chunkB.[0] < chunkA.[0] then Array.append [| chunkB.[0] |] (merge chunkA (remove chunkB))
    else Array.append [| chunkA.[0] |] (merge (remove chunkA) chunkB)

let rec mergesort (array : int[]) =
    let middle = array.Length / 2
    let chunkA = match middle with
                    | 1 -> [| array.[0] |]
                    | _ -> mergesort  [| for i in 0 .. middle - 1 -> array.[i]|]
    let chunkB = match array.Length - middle with
                    | 1 -> [| array.[array.Length - 1] |]
                    | _ -> mergesort [| for i in middle .. array.Length - 1 -> array.[i]|]
    merge chunkA chunkB
```

This code worked perfectly well, but I wanted to change the series of if statements in the `merge` function to a `match with` statement.

I then tried implementing the following code:

```
let rec merge (chunkA : int[]) (chunkB : int[]) =
match chunkA.Length with
| 0 when chunkA.Length = chunkB.Length -> [||]
| 0 | _ when chunkB.[0] < chunkA.[0] -> Array.append [| chunkB.[0] |] (merge chunkA (remove chunkB))
| _ -> Array.append [| chunkA.[0] |] (merge (remove chunkA) chunkB)
```

When I ran my code, Visual Studio threw an "IndexOutOfRangeException" at me, specifically here:

```
| 0 when chunkA.Length = chunkB.Length -> [||]
```

In this instance, `chunkA` was empty, but `chunkB` had a single number in it. Thus, I am not entirely sure why F# even attempted to return this case, since the lengths of chunks A and B were not the same, but I'm also confused as to why this would throw an Index error, specifically on the empty array.

In addition, I am rather new to F# and functional programming in general. If the structure or methodology in my code is not up to par, then please feel free to comment on this as well.

Also, if I'm being thick, please feel free to tell me that as well.

Many Thanks,
Luke

Comment: The debugger showed you incorrect line for some reason. The real source of error is `chunkB.[0] < chunkA.[0]`.

Comment: Also, the `| 0 | _ when chunkB.[0]` line will apply the `when` condition to **both** cases. The way `when` works often catches new F# programmers by surprise (it even [caught me by surprise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455264/incomplete-pattern-match-when-two-patterns-share-a-when-clause) last week, and I've been using F# for a while). So the `0` case here will still test the `when chunkB.[0] < chunkA.[0]` condition, and that will throw the IndexOutOfRangeException because you tried to access index 0 on an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Fyodor Soikin pointed out, the source of your exception is this line:

```
| 0 | _ when chunkB.[0] < chunkA.[0] -> Array.append [| chunkB.[0] |] (merge chunkA (remove chunkB))
```

But it might not be obvious to you why that's throwing an exception. [As I learned last week to my surprise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455264/incomplete-pattern-match-when-two-patterns-share-a-when-clause), the `when` clause in a match expression applies to *all* the cases since the previous `->`. In other words, when you write the line above, F# understands you to mean that you want the `when` clause applied to *either* the `0` case *or* the `_` case. (Which is, of course, redundant).

And that's the cause of your exception: F# sees the `0` case but still applies the `when chunkB.[0] < chunkA.[0]` test — and since `chunkA` is empty, that's always going to throw an exception. To fix this, you'll have to separate these two cases, so that the `when` applies to only the case you mean for it to apply to:

```
| 0 -> Array.append [| chunkB.[0] |] (merge chunkA (remove chunkB))
| _ when chunkB.[0] < chunkA.[0] -> Array.append [| chunkB.[0] |] (merge chunkA (remove chunkB))
```

Unfortunately, this does mean some duplication of code. In this case it's not a big deal since the duplicated code is a one-liner, but if you have a significant chunk of code that ends up duplicated because of having to split out two cases like this (where the two cases shouldn't share a `when` condition), then you could turn that duplicated chunk into a function so that it's not duplicated any more.

**Edit:** I just noticed a section of your code that could be simpler. Your original code included:

```
let chunkA = match middle with
                | 1 -> [| array.[0] |]
                | _ -> mergesort  [| for i in 0 .. middle - 1 -> array.[i]|]
let chunkB = match array.Length - middle with
                | 1 -> [| array.[array.Length - 1] |]
                | _ -> mergesort [| for i in middle .. array.Length - 1 -> array.[i]|]
```

What you're doing here is taking a slice of the array, but F# has a very convenient syntax for slicing arrays: `array.[start..end]` where `start` and `end` are the inclusive indices of the slice you want. So the expression `[| for i in 0 .. middle - 1 -> array.[i]|]` can be simplified down to `array.[0 .. middle - 1]`, and the expression `[| for i in middle .. array.Length - 1 -> array.[i]|]` can be simplified down to `array.[middle .. array.Length - 1]`. Let's replace those expressions in your code and see what we get:

```
let chunkA = match middle with
                | 1 -> [| array.[0] |]
                | _ -> mergesort  array.[0 .. middle - 1]
let chunkB = match array.Length - middle with
                | 1 -> [| array.[array.Length - 1] |]
                | _ -> mergesort array.[middle .. array.Length - 1]
```

Now, looking at this, I notice that the `1` condition in both cases is actually dealing with the exact same array slice as the `_` condition; the only difference is that if middle is 1, you don't call `mergesort`. How do I know that it's the exact same array slice? Well, if `middle` is 1, then the `array.[0 .. middle-1]` expression would become `array.[0..0]`, which is a slice of length 1 in the array starting at index 0, exactly equivelant to `[| array.[0] |]`. And if `array.Length` is exactly 1 more than `middle`, then the `array.[middle .. array.Length - 1]` expression is going to be `array.[middle .. middle]`, which is exactly equivalent to `[| array.[middle] |]`.

So if it weren't for the call to `mergesort`, we could consolidate these two expressions. And there's a pretty simple way to do so, in fact! Simply move the length check to the top of `mergesort`, like so:

```
let rec mergesort (array : int[]) =
    if array.Length < 2 then
        array  // Arrays of length 0 or 1 are already sorted
    else
        // rest of mergesort function goes here
```

And now you can consolidate the two cases of your `match` safely, knowing that you won't hit an infinite-recursion loop:

```
let middle = array.Length / 2
let chunkA = mergesort array.[0 .. middle - 1]
let chunkB = mergesort array.[middle .. array.Length - 1]
merge chunkA chunkB
```

Putting all this together, my suggested version of your original `mergesort` function looks like:

```
let rec mergesort (array : int[]) =
    if array.Length < 2 then
        array  // Arrays of length 0 or 1 are already sorted
    else
        let middle = array.Length / 2
        let chunkA = mergesort array.[0 .. middle - 1]
        let chunkB = mergesort array.[middle .. array.Length - 1]
        merge chunkA chunkB
```

As a bonus, this version of `mergesort` doesn't have the subtle bug your original version had: you forgot to consider the empty-array case. Calling your original `mergesort` on an empty array would produce an infinite loop. You'll probably benefit more from working it out for yourself than from me explaining how, so I'll just mention that in F# `for i in 0 .. -1` is not an error, but will go through the `for` loop zero times (i.e., the `for` loop's body will not be executed). And likewise, `array.[0..-1]` is not an error, but will produce an empty array. Armed with the knowledge of that detail, you should be able to work through the code of your original `mergesort` function and see that it would infinitely loop if you passed it an empty string. (Although since your `mergesort` call in that infinite loop is in not tail position, it would not be a tail call. And so the stack would eventually overflow, saving you from a "true" infinite loop).

Comment: In that case, is there any real reason to use the "match with" statement? Is there any benefit over using this rather than an "If else"?

Comment: No, there's no real benefit, and an `if else` would be easier to read. `match` statements are easier to read in some cases, but in this case it doesn't look like there's any ease-of-reading benefit to the `match`. Also, I just noticed something in your code that could be simplified; I'm about to edit my answer to include another suggestion.

Comment: @Luke - Updated my answer with a suggestion for how your `mergesort` function could read more cleanly (including a bugfix).

Comment: Thanks very much for the time and effort spent informing me about this - its really helped and I appreciate it greatly. F# seems to be a really neat language but I'm still getting to grips with it. Thanks again!